# Guzzle: Access uploaded files in history middleware

Tags: php, guzzle, psr-7

I'm trying to access an uploaded file in the history middleware for Guzzle (v6).

My actual code receives a request (so is using the `ServerRequestInterface`), then uses Guzzle to send the request elsewhere.

I'm trying to test uploaded files going through this layer, but I can't seem to access them in the Request object returned by Guzzle's middleware.

Example code:

```
<?php


use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Handler\MockHandler;
use GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;
use GuzzleHttp\Middleware;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\UploadedFile;

class DoNotCommitTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    public function testUploads()
    {
        $request = new ServerRequest('GET', 'http://example.com/bla');

        $file = new UploadedFile('test', 100, \UPLOAD_ERR_OK);

        $request = $request->withUploadedFiles([$file]);
        $this->assertCount(1, $request->getUploadedFiles());

        // Mock Guzzle request, assert on the request it 'sent'

        $mock = new MockHandler([
            function (ServerRequest $request, array $options) {
                // This fails...
                $this->assertCount(1, $request->getUploadedFiles());
            }
        ]);

        $historyContainer = [];
        $history = Middleware::history($historyContainer);

        $handler = HandlerStack::create($mock);
        $handler->push($history);

        $client = new Client(['handler' => $handler]);

        $client->send($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow execution chain, `$client->send($request)` at some point calls private `applyOptions` function, which calls `Psr7\modify_request` function. If you look at `Psr7\modify_request` [function](https://github.com/guzzle/psr7/blob/master/src/functions.php):

```
...
if ($request instanceof ServerRequestInterface) {
    return new ServerRequest(
        isset($changes['method']) ? $changes['method'] : $request->getMethod(),
        $uri,
        $headers,
        isset($changes['body']) ? $changes['body'] : $request->getBody(),
        isset($changes['version'])
            ? $changes['version']
            : $request->getProtocolVersion(),
        $request->getServerParams()
    );
}
...
```

It returns new `ServerRequest` object without preserving your uploaded files array (`ServerRequest` object doesn't have the `uploadedFiles` as an argument in the constructor). That's why you lost your `uploadedFiles` array.

**UPDATE**:

I created an [issue](https://github.com/guzzle/psr7/issues/177) and a [pull request](https://github.com/guzzle/psr7/pull/178) to fix it.

Comment: Thanks. I've been away for a few days, and was about to open an issue just now. I agree that it looks to be a bug with Guzzle's PSR7 library, although I was worried I was using it wrong. I'll mark this as the accepted answer, and you definitely deserve the bounty.